# FileSystem Implementation, Listing File Path through Binary Search Tree

Tags: java

I'm working on a FileSystem implementation, and I'm having trouble with my Binary Search Tree `locate` method. Right now the way I have it structured. It will add additional files or something else that I'm unable to figure out.

As an example, I have the tree:

```
      /
     / \
    a   b
   /   / \
  c   h   q
 /
x
```

If the user inputs `locate h`, my program will output `/acxh`.
When the user inputs `locate h`, the output SHOULD be `/bh`

Here is my `FileSystem` class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FileSystem {
private Directory root;
private Directory wDir;
private ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();

// Constructor
public FileSystem() {

}

// Constructor with parameters
public FileSystem(Directory root) {
    this.root = root;
    wDir = root;
    files.add(root);
}

// Returns the FileSystem's files
public ArrayList<File> getFiles() {
    return files;
}

// Returns the working directory
public Directory getWDir() {
    return wDir;
}

// Sets the working directory
public void setWDir(Directory d) {
    wDir = d;
}

// Returns the root file. This will always be / in our program
public File getRoot() {
    return root;
}

public File getFile(File f, String name) {
    if (f.isDirectory()) {
        for (File c : ((Directory) f).getChildren()) {
            if (c.getName().equals(name))
                return c;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

// Currently only used in cat method, getFile is better
File findFile(File f, String name) {
    if (f.getName().equals(name))
        return f;
    File file = null;
    if (f.isDirectory()) {
        for (File c : ((Directory) f).getChildren()) {
            file = findFile(c, name);
            if (file != null)
                break;
        }
    }
    return file;
}

// Returns true if file is found
boolean isFile(String name) {
    File file = null;
    file = getFile(wDir, name);
    if (file != null) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// Creates Directory
public void mkdir(String path) {
    files.add(new Directory(path));

    int size = files.size();

    // Sets the parent
    files.get(size - 1).setParent(wDir);
    // Sets the child
    wDir.addChild(files.get(size - 1));
}

// Changes working directory
public void cd(String s) {
    if (s.equals("..")) {
        if (wDir != root) {
            wDir = wDir.getParent();
        }
    } else if (s.equals("/")) {
        wDir = root;
    } else {
        wDir = (Directory) getFile(wDir, s);
    }

}

// Provides absolute filename
public void pwd() {
    if (wDir == root) {
        System.out.println("/");
    } else {
        System.out.println(wDir.getPath());
    }
}

// Lists children of current working directory
public void ls() {
    ArrayList<File> children = wDir.getChildren();
    if (children != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
            String childName = children.get(i).getName();
            System.out.print(childName + " ");
        }
    }
}

// Lists children of file(s) inputted by user
public void ls(File f) {
    if (f instanceof TextFile) {
        System.out.println(f.getPath());
    } else {
        ArrayList<File> children = ((Directory) f).getChildren();
        if (children != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
                String childName = children.get(i).getName();
                System.out.print(childName + " ");
            }
        }
    }

}

public void recLS(File f, String location) {
    System.out.println(location + ":");
    ls(f);
    System.out.println("");
    if (f.isDirectory()) {
        ArrayList<File> children = ((Directory) f).getChildren();

        for (File c : children) {
            location += "/" + c.getName();
        }
        for (File c : children) {
            recLS(c, location);
        }
    }
}

// Creates a TextFile or edit's TextFile's content if already exists in the
// tree
public void edit(String name, String content) {
    files.add(new TextFile(name, content));

    // Setting TextFile parent
    files.get(files.size() - 1).setParent(wDir);
    // Setting Parent's child
    wDir.addChild(files.get(files.size() - 1));

}

// Prints the content of TextFile
public void cat(String name) {
    File f = findFile(root, name);
    System.out.println(((TextFile) f).getContent());
}

public void updatedb(Indexer i) throws IOException {
    i.index(files);
}

public String locate(String s, Indexer i) {
    return i.locate(s);
}

}
```

Here is my `Indexer` class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Entry implements Comparable<Entry> {
String word;
ArrayList<Integer> page = new ArrayList<Integer>();

Entry(String word) {
    this.word = word;
}

public int compareTo(Entry e) {
    return word.compareTo(e.word);
}
}

class Indexer {

private BinarySearchTree<Entry> bst;

public void index(ArrayList<File> files) throws IOException {
    bst = new BinarySearchTree<Entry>();
    int fileCount = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {
        String name = files.get(i).getName();
        indexName(name, fileCount++);
    }
}

private void indexName(String name, int fileCount) {
    Entry e = new Entry(name);
    Entry r = bst.find(e);
    if (r != null) {
        r.page.add(fileCount);
    } else {
        e.page.add(fileCount);
        bst.add(e);
    }
}

public String locate(String s) {
    Entry e = new Entry(s);
    ArrayList<String> path = new ArrayList<String>();
    bst.locateHelper(e, bst.root, path);

    String word = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < path.size(); i++) {
        word += path.get(i);
    }

    return word;
}

}
```

Here is my `BinarySearchTree` class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BinarySearchTree<E extends Comparable> extends BinaryTree<E> {

private boolean addReturn;
private E deletedItem;

boolean add(E item) {
    root = add(root, item);
    return addReturn;
}

private Node<E> add(Node<E> n, E item) {
    if (n == null) {
        addReturn = true;
        return new Node<E>(item);
    } else if (item.compareTo(n.data) == 0) {
        addReturn = false;
        return n;
    } else if (item.compareTo(n.data) < 0) {
        n.leftChild = add(n.leftChild, item);
        return n;
    } else {
        n.rightChild = add(n.rightChild, item);
        return n;
    }
}

public E find(E target) {
    return find(target, root);
}

private E find(E target, Node<E> node) {
    if (node == null) {
        return null;
    }
    int result = target.compareTo(node.data);
    if (result == 0) {
        return node.data;
    }
    if (result < 0) {
        return find(target, node.leftChild);
    }
    return find(target, node.rightChild);
}

public String locateHelper(Entry e, Node<Entry> node, ArrayList<String> path) {
    if (node == null) {
        return null;
    }

    int result = e.compareTo(node.data);
    if (result == 0) {
        path.add(node.data.word);
        return node.data.word;
    }
    if (result < 0) {
        path.add(node.data.word);
        return locateHelper(e, node.leftChild, path);
    }
    path.add(node.data.word);
    return locateHelper(e, node.rightChild, path);
}

}
```

I apologize for having a lot of code in the post, I know I'm supposed to keep it minimal, but I'm sure you will need to look at these 3 classes at least to provide some help. If anything else is needed just let me know and I'll edit this post to provide it.

Comment: Hint: test your binary search tree independently of your filesystem simulator to decide which one is causing the problem.  Also, you should tell us both what behavior you expect as well as what you actually get.

Comment: Binary search trees are supposed to have nodes with "lower" values as a left child node, and "higher" values as a right child node, but your example doesn't seem to show that.

Comment: How can I make my inputs have lower values? Instead of doing a `for` loop through my `files` arraylist that stores all of the files in the tree should I enter them in by paths? @GerardoFigueroa and, @JeffreyBosboom if the user inputs `locate h` my program will output `/acxh` instead of the correct output which is `/bh` I have a tree example at the top of my post.